# TYPO3 CASE with Templavoilà FCE id

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x, templavoila

Is it possible to access the id of a Templavoilà Data Structure / FCE for a CASE ?

I tried this which didn't work :

```
10 = CASE
10 {
 key.field = tx_templavoilaplus_datastructure
 100 = TEXT
 …
 default = TEXT
 …
}
```

Thank you ! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field for the Data Structure in tt_content for TemplaVoila is `tx_templavoila_ds`. If you're using TemplaVoila Plus it's `tx_templavoilaplus_ds`.

Also, only the fields in the data structure are available directly. However, TemplaVoila loads the parent record data in the register. You can access it using `key.data = register:tx_templavoila_pi1.parentRec.tx_templavoila_ds`. For TemplaVoila Plus it's `key.data = register:tx_templavoilaplus_pi1.parentRec.tx_templavoilaplus_ds`

Comment: Thank you, that's one first step, I had that wrong. But it still doesn't work… What I want to do is display a link only if it is in the right FCE.

Comment: I tried `5 = TEXT` `5.value.field = tx_templavoilaplus_ds`, which didn't return anything…

Comment: But… even a `page:title` doesn't give me anything…

Comment: It's been a while since I've used TemplaVoila, but if I remember correctly you had to save the TO mapping again after changing the DS.

Comment: I don't understand, everything is saved properly. In the FCE, I link a particular field to a Typoscript Object Path. In `lib.particularfield` in my TS template, `5.value = some text` works, but not `5.value.field = [anything]`

Comment: Does `5.field = tx_templavoilaplus_ds` work (so without `value`)?

Comment: No it doesn't either

Comment: And `5.field = uid`?

Comment: Not either, I tried several combinations already, none worked with `.field`

Comment: Strange. That should work. Though I've never worked with TemplaVoila Plus. It could work different than vanilla TemplaVoila.

Comment: I think I know why it doesn't work. I just can't use title, bodytext, etc… since I'm in a FCE. I can only use the fields which are set up in the FCE with TV.

Comment: Right, sorry, I remember now. It's been too long :) TemplaVoila loads the parent record data in the register. You can access it using `5.data = register:tx_templavoila_pi1.parentRec.uid`. If TemplaVoila Plus does something similar it's probably `5.data = register:tx_templavoilaplus_pi1.parentRec.uid`.

Comment: It works ! Thank you @Rudy for your help. I've used `key.data = register:tx_templavoilaplus_pi1.parentRec.tx_templavoilaplus_ds`. If you'd be so kind to write an answer, I will mark it as the right one =)